# Compiling IronPython with pyc - No module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, ironpython, pyc, python.net

I have some IronPython code which runs fine from within Visual Studio.  It uses numpy.  However when I compile it with pyc it compiles successfully BUT when I run it I get a "No module named numpy" error.

I've tried copying various DLLs from the IronPython DLLs directory (basically all the numpy ones) but I still get the error.

I've tried Google but no success, so any help much appreciated.

I'm running IronPython version 2.7.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you show your call to pyc and your import statements from your code? I bet you are not adding the DLL's correctly with pyc and your import statements are taking advantage of visual studio default search paths.

Answer (score -1):

Try Enthought's NumPy implementation:

http://www.enthought.com/repo/.iron/